# Zoom on a PostGIS vector layer in a new project with PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

I load into a PostGIS database, 2 shapefiles of the [QGIS sample data](https://qgis.org/downloads/data/) :

- alaska.shp
- storagep.shp

with the shell code :

```bsh
shp2pgsql -s 2964 storagep.shp public.storagep > storagep.sql
shp2pgsql -s 2964 alaska.shp public.alaska > alaska.sql
psql -h localhost -U postgres -d postgres -f storagep.sql
psql -h localhost -U postgres -d postgres -f alaska.sql
```

Under QGIS 3.6.1, I execute **in a new project** the following code in the QGIS Python editor :

```python
def loadPgLayer(instance, vl, path, name, data_filter=""):
    """load a postgis vector layer"""
    vl.setDataSource(path, name, "postgres")
    if vl.isValid() and vl.setSubsetString(data_filter):
        instance.addMapLayer(vl)

canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
instance = QgsProject.instance()

uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri_params = dict(aHost="127.0.0.1",
                  aPort="5432",
                  aDatabase="postgres",
                  aUsername="postgres",
                  aPassword="")
uri.setConnection(**uri_params)

vl_alaska = QgsVectorLayer()
vl_storagep = QgsVectorLayer()

name = "alaska"
uri.setDataSource("public", name, "geom")
path = uri.uri(False)
loadPgLayer(instance, vl_alaska, path, name)

name = "storagep"
uri.setDataSource("public", name, "geom")
path = uri.uri(False)
loadPgLayer(instance, vl_storagep, path, name)

# set the project crs
instance.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(2964))
# zoom on vl_storagep extent
rect = canvas.mapSettings().layerExtentToOutputExtent(vl_storagep, vl_storagep.extent())
canvas.setExtent(rect)
# for update view
canvas.refresh()
```

This code load the two PostGIS vector layers but doesn't zoom on the extents of **vl_storagep** layer.

But, after executing this code above, in the QGIS Python console I enter this piece of code below again :

```
canvas.setExtent(rect)
# for update view
canvas.refresh()
```

and it zooms on the desired extents.

If I try this kind of code with Shapefiles Vector Layers, everything is good, but as soon as it's PostGIS Vector Layers, this malfunction (?) appears.

For information :

- OS : Ubuntu 18.04
- QGIS : 3.6.1
- PostGIS :

```sql
SELECT postgis_version();
--> 2.4 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what the issue is? You said your initial code does not zoom to the extent of the PostGIS layers but when adding an extra line `canvas.refresh()`, it solves your problem?

Comment: I've edit my post. The `canvas.refresh()` code is here just for map's aesthetic. I execute a first time the whole PyQGIS code and after, in the console, just with `canvas.setExtent(rect)` (as objects are still in memory), it zoom at the right extent. But I don't achieve this in one go.

Comment: Before you define `rect`, try adding `vl_storagep = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('storagep')[0]` so that you're defining `vl_storagep` again but as a full PostGIS layer and not an empty `QgsVectorLayer()` object.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work. I don't think it's related to the vector layer because another code like `canvas.zoomScale(10000)` instead of `canvas.setExtent(rect)` doesn't work too. It seams like QGIS, after loading PostGIS layers, update canvas extents with the extent of all layers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need refresh canvas and wait to finish render before setExtent.

```
canvas.refresh()
canvas.waitWhileRendering()
```

**complet code sample**

```
def loadPgLayer(instance, vl, path, name, data_filter=""):
    """load a postgis vector layer"""
    vl.setDataSource(path, name, "postgres")
    if vl.isValid() and vl.setSubsetString(data_filter):
        instance.addMapLayer(vl)

canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
instance = QgsProject.instance()

uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri_params = dict(aHost="127.0.0.1",
                  aPort="5433",
                  aDatabase="test",
                  aUsername="postgres",
                  aPassword="postgres")
uri.setConnection(**uri_params)

vl_alaska = QgsVectorLayer()
vl_storagep = QgsVectorLayer()

name = "alaska"
uri.setDataSource("public", name, "geom")
path = uri.uri(False)
loadPgLayer(instance, vl_alaska, path, name)

name = "storagep"
uri.setDataSource("public", name, "geom")
path = uri.uri(False)
loadPgLayer(instance, vl_storagep, path, name)

# set the project crs
instance.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(2964))

canvas.refresh()
canvas.waitWhileRendering()

# zoom on vl_storagep extent
rect = canvas.mapSettings().layerExtentToOutputExtent(vl_storagep, vl_storagep.extent())
canvas.setExtent(rect)
# for update view
canvas.refresh()
```

[image]

Comment: It's exactly what I'm looking for, it's perfect. Thank you for this (and all your contributions for the QGIS project).