# Add layer to QGIS 3 map from processing script

Tags: python, qgis-processing, vector-layer

I would load to QGIS map a vector layer from processing script. I'm trying to use `QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)`.
It works if I run the code from pyqgis console:

```
layer=QgsVectorLayer('fileName.shp',"name","ogr")
if not layer.isValid():
   print('layer failed to load')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

but it cannot works if I run the same from processing script. No error alerts are shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [a previous answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/397551/processing-script-to-load-vector-layer-from-postgis-connection-string-error/398355#398355) in another processing context, the following should do what you want

```py
context.temporaryLayerStore().addMapLayer(layer)
context.addLayerToLoadOnCompletion(
            layer.id(),
            QgsProcessingContext.LayerDetails('SQL layer',
                                              context.project(),
                                              'LAYER'))
```

See both [method `temporaryLayerStore` doc](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingContext.html#a0c919837903847150ee62df2f9f83327) and [method `addLayerToLoadOnCompletion` doc](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingContext.html#a7cb37b570ec45df2407ef1007e9600ca)