# Processing script to load raster layer from PostGIS

Tags: raster, postgis, pyqgis

I'd like to have a Python script that loads a raster layer contained in a PostGIS database into my QGIS project.

I found this very useful script that works for loading a vector layer : [Processing script to load vector layer from PostGIS - connection string error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/397551/processing-script-to-load-vector-layer-from-postgis-connection-string-error/398355#398355)

and I wanted to adapt it for raster layers, but my coding knowledge is very limited and I can't manage to make it work.

What I tried to do is change all the "geom" occurencies by "rast" and to adapt the functions (basically I mostly changed "vector" by "raster" everywhere).

The script is now the following :

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsProcessingException,
                       QgsProcessingContext,
                       QgsProcessingParameterString,
                       QgsProcessingOutputVectorLayer,
                       QgsProcessingOutputRasterLayer,
                       QgsProcessingOutputString,
                       QgsProcessingParameterNumber,
                       QgsVectorLayer,
                       QgsRasterLayer,
                       QgsDataSourceUri,
                       QgsProject)
from qgis import processing


class ExampleProcessingAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    """
    This is an example algorithm that takes string inputs,
    to provide to DB connexion
    """

    def tr(self, string):
        """
        Returns a translatable string with the self.tr() function.
        """
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

    def createInstance(self):
        # Must return a new copy of your algorithm.
        return ExampleProcessingAlgorithm()

    def name(self):
        """
        Returns the unique algorithm name.
        """
        return 'postgresconnexion'

    def displayName(self):
        """
        Returns the translated algorithm name.
        """
        return self.tr('Load PostGIS merged')

    def group(self):
        """
        Returns the name of the group this algorithm belongs to.
        """
        return self.tr('Example scripts')

    def groupId(self):
        """
        Returns the unique ID of the group this algorithm belongs
        to.
        """
        return 'examplescripts'

    def shortHelpString(self):
        """
        Returns a localised short help string for the algorithm.
        """
        return self.tr('Example algorithm short description')

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        """
        Here we define the inputs and outputs of the algorithm.
        """
        # 'INPUT' is the recommended name for the main input
        # parameter.
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterString(
                'HOST',
                self.tr('Host'),
                defaultValue = 'localhost'
            )
        )
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterNumber(
                'PORT',
                self.tr('Port'),
                defaultValue = 5432
            )
        )
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterString(
                'USERNAME',
                self.tr('Username'),
            )
        )
        # 'OUTPUT' is the recommended name for the main output
        # parameter.
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterString(
                'PASSWORD',
                self.tr('Password')
            )
        )
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterString(
                'DATABASE',
                self.tr('Database')
            )
        )

        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterString(
                'SCHEMA',
                self.tr('schema'),
                defaultValue = 'public'
            )
        )
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterString(
                'LAYERNAME',
                self.tr('Layer name'),
                defaultValue = 'Name of the layer'
            )
        )

        self.addOutput(
            QgsProcessingOutputRasterLayer(
                'LAYER',
                self.tr('Raster layer'),
                QgsProcessing.TypeRaster
            )
        )

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        """
        Here is where the processing itself takes place.
        """
        # First, we get the count of features from the INPUT layer.
        # This layer is defined as a QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource
        # parameter, so it is retrieved by calling
        # self.parameterAsSource.
        host = self.parameterAsString (parameters,
                                                     'HOST',
                                                     context)

        # Retrieve the buffer distance and raster cell size numeric
        # values. Since these are numeric values, they are retrieved
        # using self.parameterAsDouble.
        port = self.parameterAsString (parameters, 'PORT',
                                            context)
        username = self.parameterAsString (parameters, 'USERNAME',
                                                context)

        password = self.parameterAsString (parameters, 'PASSWORD',
                                                context)

        database = self.parameterAsString (parameters, 'DATABASE',
                                                context)

        schema = self.parameterAsString (parameters, 'SCHEMA', context)
        
        layername = self.parameterAsString (parameters, 'LAYERNAME', context)

        uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
        uri.setConnection(host, port, database, username, password)
        uri.setDataSource(schema, layername, "rast")

        layer = QgsRasterLayer(uri.uri(), layername, "postgres")

        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}
        
        if not layer.isValid():
            raise QgsProcessingException(self.tr("""This layer is invalid!
                Please check the PostGIS log for error messages."""))

        context.temporaryLayerStore().addMapLayer(layer)
        context.addLayerToLoadOnCompletion(
            layer.id(),
            QgsProcessingContext.LayerDetails('SQL layer',
                                              context.project(),
                                              'LAYER'))

        # Return the results
        return {'LAYER': layer.id()}
```

But when I run it I get this error :

```
          File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/script/ScriptEditorDialog.py", line 253, in runAlgorithm
          alg.initAlgorithm()
          File "", line 122, in initAlgorithm
         TypeError: QgsProcessingOutputRasterLayer(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
          overload 1: too many arguments
          overload 2: argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
```

And I don't really know what to do about it.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor to QgsProcessingOutputRasterLayer takes only two arguments. See https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.26/core/QgsProcessingOutputRasterLayer.html .

Remove the `QgsProcessing.TypeRaster` argument from the algorithm output definition (last part of your `initAlgorithm` function).

edit:

And add an extra argument to the `QgsProcessingContext.LayerDetails` call, which should read

```
QgsProcessingContext.LayerDetails(
   'Raster Layer',context.project()
   ,'LAYER'
   ,QgsProcessingUtils.LayerHint.Raster
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed that. There is still another error though: 

Erroneous query: SELECT 0, array_agg(DISTINCT st_srid("rast")::text || ':' || UPPER(geometrytype("rast")) || ':' || ST_Zmflag("rast")) FROM (SELECT "rast" FROM "public"."merge") AS _unused returned 7 [ERROR: function geometrytype(raster) does not exist. LINE 1: ...gg(DISTINCT st_srid("rast")::text || ':' || UPPER(geometryty...

Comment: with a HINT that I would translate as "No function corresponds to the given name and argument types. You need to add explicite type conversions"

Comment: Some part of the script still tries to operate on a vector layer, but I cannot really see which part.

Comment: I hope it was the LayerDetails LayerHint, but I think it is (see edited answer)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this didn't change the error. I posted the solution I finally found.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @til_b for your help.

I tried to add the argument to the QgsProcessingContext.LayerDetails call as you suggested, but it didn't change the error.
I tried several other things, and I finally managed to find the last missing detail.

I had :

```
layer = QgsRasterLayer(uri.uri(), layername, "postgres")
```

But it had to be :

```
layer = QgsRasterLayer(uri.uri(), layername, "postgresraster")
```

So here is the final script that is working perfectly:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsProcessingException,
                       QgsProcessingContext,
                       QgsProcessingParameterString,
                       QgsProcessingOutputVectorLayer,
                       QgsProcessingOutputRasterLayer,
                       QgsProcessingOutputString,
                       QgsProcessingParameterNumber,
                       QgsVectorLayer,
                       QgsRaster,
                       QgsRasterLayer,
                       QgsDataSourceUri,
                       QgsApplication,
                       QgsProject)
from qgis import processing


class ExampleProcessingAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    """
    This is an example algorithm that takes string inputs,
    to provide to DB connexion
    """

    def tr(self, string):
        """
        Returns a translatable string with the self.tr() function.
        """
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

    def createInstance(self):
        # Must return a new copy of your algorithm.
        return ExampleProcessingAlgorithm()

    def name(self):
        """
        Returns the unique algorithm name.
        """
        return 'postgresconnexion'

    def displayName(self):
        """
        Returns the translated algorithm name.
        """
        return self.tr('Load PostGIS merged')

    def group(self):
        """
        Returns the name of the group this algorithm belongs to.
        """
        return self.tr('Example scripts')

    def groupId(self):
        """
        Returns the unique ID of the group this algorithm belongs
        to.
        """
        return 'examplescripts'

    def shortHelpString(self):
        """
        Returns a localised short help string for the algorithm.
        """
        return self.tr('Example algorithm short description')

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        """
        Here we define the inputs and outputs of the algorithm.
        """
        # 'INPUT' is the recommended name for the main input
        # parameter.
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterString(
                'HOST',
                self.tr('Host'),
                defaultValue = 'localhost'
            )
        )
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterNumber(
                'PORT',
                self.tr('Port'),
                defaultValue = 5432
            )
        )
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterString(
                'USERNAME',
                self.tr('Username'),
            )
        )
        # 'OUTPUT' is the recommended name for the main output
        # parameter.
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterString(
                'PASSWORD',
                self.tr('Password'),
            )
        )
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterString(
                'DATABASE',
                self.tr('Database'),
            )
        )

        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterString(
                'SCHEMA',
                self.tr('schema'),
                defaultValue = 'public'
            )
        )
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterString(
                'LAYERNAME',
                self.tr('Layer name'),
            )
        )

        self.addOutput(
            QgsProcessingOutputRasterLayer(
                'LAYER',
                self.tr('Raster layer')
            )
        )

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        """
        Here is where the processing itself takes place.
        """
        # First, we get the count of features from the INPUT layer.
        # This layer is defined as a QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource
        # parameter, so it is retrieved by calling
        # self.parameterAsSource.
        host = self.parameterAsString (parameters,
                                                     'HOST',
                                                     context)

        # Retrieve the buffer distance and raster cell size numeric
        # values. Since these are numeric values, they are retrieved
        # using self.parameterAsDouble.
        port = self.parameterAsString (parameters, 'PORT',
                                            context)
        username = self.parameterAsString (parameters, 'USERNAME',
                                                context)

        password = self.parameterAsString (parameters, 'PASSWORD',
                                                context)

        database = self.parameterAsString (parameters, 'DATABASE',
                                                context)

        schema = self.parameterAsString (parameters, 'SCHEMA', context)
        
        layername = self.parameterAsString (parameters, 'LAYERNAME', context)

        uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
        uri.setConnection(host, port, database, username, password)
        uri.setDataSource(schema, layername, "rast")

        layer = QgsRasterLayer(uri.uri(), layername, "postgresraster")

        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}
        
        if not layer.isValid():
            raise QgsProcessingException(self.tr("""This layer is invalid!
                Please check the PostGIS log for error messages."""))

        context.temporaryLayerStore().addMapLayer(layer)
        context.addLayerToLoadOnCompletion(
            layer.id(),
            QgsProcessingContext.LayerDetails('SQL Layer',context.project()
                                              ,'LAYER')
                                              )

        # Return the results
        return {'LAYER': layer.id()}
```